# If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2$ diverges, then $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+a_n)$ diverges to $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, infinite-product

Prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2$ diverges, then $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+a_n)$ diverges to $0$.

We assume that $\{a_n\}$ is a real sequence.

An infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+a_n)$ diverges to $0$ if $1+a_n \ne 0 \,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+a_n)=0$.

Any hint or reference will be appreciated.

Comment: Would it not be that the infinite product **con**verges to $0$?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer It should be diverge to $0$ according to my book "A Course of Modern Analysis".

Comment: I found an example $\prod \left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ for this statement. I am not sure if the product is $0$ or not.

Comment: Hint: take a log and taylor expand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\log(1+t)  \sim t - t^2/2$ as $t \to 0$ so $t - t^2/4 \ge \log(1+t)$ for real $t$ with $|t|$ sufficiently small (in fact it is true for $-1 < t < 2.532354756$ approximately).  So when $a_i, i = k \ldots m$ are in this interval

$$ \prod_{i=k}^m (1 + a_i) = \exp \left(\sum_{i=k}^m \log(1 + a_i) \right)
\le \ldots $$

Comment: I think I got it! Thanks!

Comment: @Integrand Since we assume that $\sum a_n$ converges, we have $\lim a_n = 0$. We can choose a very small $\varepsilon > 0$. Then there exists a $N$ such that $|a_n| < \varepsilon \, \forall n \ge N$. That avoids the problem $1+a_i$ cannot be $0$. Pick $\varepsilon = 0.5$ for example.

Comment: "$\log(1+t)  \sim t - t^2/2$"  How is that different from $\log(1+t)  \sim t ?$

Comment: Better to write $\log(1+t) = t - t^2/2 + O(t^3)$

Comment: @Integrand What's wrong with $t$ near $-1$? $\log(1+t) < -5/4 < t - t^2/4$ for $-1 < t < \exp(-5/4)-1$.